# how to interpolate recursive search in zsh

Tags: zsh, glob, variable-substitution

I want to use an environment variable in a command with recursive search.

```
export RAILS_FILE_EXTENSIONS='(erb|feature|haml|jrxml|js|rake|rb|rxml|scss|xml|yml)'
ls **/*.${RAILS_FILE_EXTENSIONS}
```

It does not work this way. How should it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell zsh to interpret `RAILS_FILE_EXTENSIONS` as a pattern rather than a raw string when substituting its value, with the `~` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
RAILS_FILE_EXTENSIONS='(erb|feature|haml|jrxml|js|rake|rb|rxml|scss|xml|yml)'
ls **/*.$~RAILS_FILE_EXTENSIONS
```